What is the maximum proficiency level for fighting skills?
Fighting skills can have their proficiency level increased from repeated use. Is there a maximum proficiency level where a fighting skill will stop leveling up?


According to this Reddit page,

Max Level is 15 which is around 99999 [skill points] or something along those lines of skill points.
Higher levels can give a range of different bonuses either in range, damage or allow you to repeat the move multiple times depending on the skill.
You can check the skill level bonuses on the skill page

